# Add the ability to comment on the Tag Info synonyms page

Tags: feature-request, comments, tag-synonyms

It would be nice to be able to comment upon pending tag synonyms so that one could <s>talk some sense into the maniacs who voted for</s> discuss the pros and cons of a pending synonym.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be nice if there was some mechanism that if someone wanted to start a conversation on the synonym, it would auto-create a post on Meta for it.  So only the synonyms that people wanted to discuss would generate the post.